# CSS + Icon = Logo

Tags: css, icons

How can I make an icon-based, letter-based logo using only CSS and readily available icon sets?

I have tried loading icon sets from standard graphics packages but the results were unsatisfactory.

[Here is a solution I tried using CSS + Font Awesome](http://jsbin.com/najakoraqa/edit?html,output).

http://jsbin.com/najakoraqa/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Logos Using CSS + Font-Awesome</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <style>

    body {
      font-size: 100px;
      color: red;
    }

    .fa-logo:before {
      font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-style: italic;
    }

    .fa-l:before {
      content: 'L';
      margin-right: -.2em;
    }

    .fa-z:before {
      content: 'Z';
      margin-left: -.4em;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <span class="fa fa-logo fa-l"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-bolt"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-logo fa-z"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700);
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*,
:before,
:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.title {
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  padding: 1em 1em .25em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.title:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 240px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-left: -120px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
}
/* Clip text element */

.clip-text {
  font-size: 8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .25em;
  padding: .5em .75em;
  text-align: center;
  /* Color fallback */
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.clip-text:before,
.clip-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
/* Background */

.clip-text:before {
  z-index: -2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: inherit;
}
/* Text Background (black zone) */

.clip-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: .125em;
  right: .125em;
  bottom: .125em;
  left: .125em;
  background-color: #000;
}
/* Change the background position to display letter when the black zone isn't here */

.clip-text--no-textzone:before {
  background-position: -.65em 0;
}
.clip-text--no-textzone:after {
  content: none;
}
/* Use Background-size cover for photo background and no-repeat background */

.clip-text--cover,
.clip-text--cover:before {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
/* Background image from http://thepatternlibrary.com/ and http://lorempixel.com */

.clip-text_one {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/7);
}
.clip-text_two {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract);
}
.clip-text_tree {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/2);
}
.clip-text_four {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/4);
}
.clip-text_five {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/5);
}
.clip-text_six {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/9);
}
.clip-text_seven {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/8);
}
.clip-text_eight {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/410/200/people);
}
.clip-text_nine {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/nightlife);
}
.clip-text_ten {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/nightlife/8);
}
.clip-text_eleven {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/fashion/10/cc);
  background-size: cover;
}
.clip-text_twelve {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/people/7/cc);
}
.clip-text_thirteen {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/food/5/cc);
}
.clip-text_fourteen {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/city/9/cc);
}
.clip-text_fifteen {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/nightlife/5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="title">Play with background-clip text</p>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_one">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_fifteen clip-text--no-textzone">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_twelve clip-text--cover">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_tree clip-text--no-textzone">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_two">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_fourteen clip-text--cover">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_tree">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_eleven clip-text--cover">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_four">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_five">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_six">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_seven">Sam</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_eight">Sam</div>

  <div class="clip-text clip-text_nine">JINTOS</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_ten">JINTOS</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_thirteen clip-text--cover">JINTOS</div>
</div>
```

These are 15 examples i created u can change the background image or text as per your choice and it gives a professional photoshop look. Hope you like it and please rate it if you do! :) Thanks
-regards Sam

Comment: i am glad you liked it. :-)

Comment: @Mowzer ANY question can be closed and voting on answers will not protect it. Suggesting deals for votes is not approved and likely to receive moderator attention leading to punitive action.

Comment: @Mowzer if you get downvoted it is only  because you question is too poor.  Rephrase it, show your issue and where you get stuck.Like with one of your try with icons sets...

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `mix-blend-mode` too without special fonts, be imaginative.

Below: `letter-spacing`, `font-size`,  and `mix-blend-mode` to simulate `background-clip:text` and `text-fill-color`.

codepen to play with live : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/mPeNXy

```css
#mxclptxt {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract);
  display:table;
  margin:1em;
  overflow:hidden
    }
p {
  background:black;
  color:white;
  font-size:100px;
  font-wheight:bold;
  text-shadow:2px 2px gray, 4px 4px gray;;
  padding:0.5em 1em;
  margin:0.5em -0.5em;
  letter-spacing:-25px;
  font-family:courier;
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
  transform:rotate(-15deg)
```

```html
<div id="mxclptxt">
  <p>My Logo</p>
</div>
```